# How decompilers combine multiple SSA form instructions into one statement?

Tags: compiler-construction, decompiler

I just wonder how decompilers combine multiple SSA form instructions into one statement? Or is there already an algorithm that can combine the instructions?

For example, (To make question simpler, I use high level language to make an example.)

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i < N-1; i++) {
  int d = 3;
  int v1 = A[i-1];
  int v2 = A[i];
  int t1 = v1+v2;
  int v3 = A[i+1];
  int sum = t1+v3;
  int res = sum / d;
  B[i] = res;
}
```

Actually this is averaging three elements array elements A[i-1], A[i], and A[i+1] and store into B. Not these instructions could be combined like,

```cpp
for(int i = 1; i < N-1; i++) {
  B[i] = (A[i-1]+A[i]+A[i+1]) / 3;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SSA is an intermediate compiler representation; the decompiler looks at the generated assembly. Chances are pretty good that the compiler chose a single register for multiple SSA statements - even though SSA does allow the compiler to make different choices.

For instance, in your example, the addition of `A[i-1]+A[i]+A[i+1]` can be done in a single register. It's an unavoidable dependency. The decompiler, looking back, only sees the single register and not the SSA statements.